# Pre-built code for checking conditional formatting not working - Type error

Tags: excel, vba, compatibility

I'm attempting to use a VBA function created by [Bob Phillips](http://www.xldynamic.com/source/xld.CFConditions.html) to check if conditional formatting has been met in a particular cell. This seems to be a respectable solution, as Google turns up a number of different references to it, but it's throwing a Type error for me. I'm using Excel 2007, and the last update made to the code was in 2005, so I assume there are some compatibility issues involved. I have already fixed one syntax error (`Set rng = rng(1, 1)` wasn't working until I inserted `.Cells`) but I'm unable to fix this one because I can't parse what the code is doing.

The function is designed specifically to evaluate conditionals based on a formula, which mine is. Here is the full code:

```
Public Function IsCFMet2(rng As Range) As Boolean

Dim oFC As FormatCondition
Dim sF1 As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iColumn As Long

   Set rng = rng.Cells(1, 1)
   If rng.FormatConditions.Count > 0 Then
      For Each oFC In rng.FormatConditions
         If oFC.Type = xlExpression Then
             're-adjust the formula back to the formula that applies
             'to the cell as relative formulae adjust to the activecell
            With Application
               iRow = rng.Row
               iColumn = rng.Column
               sF1 = .Substitute(oFC.Formula1, "ROW()", iRow)
               sF1 = .Substitute(sF1, "COLUMN()", iColumn)
               sF1 = .ConvertFormula(sF1, xlA1, xlR1C1)
               sF1 = .ConvertFormula(sF1, xlR1C1, xlA1, , rng)
            End With
       **** IsCFMet2 = rng.Parent.Evaluate(sF1)
         End If
         If IsCFMet2 Then Exit Function
     Next oFC
   End If

End Function
```

The Type Error is thrown by the starred line. I don't fully grasp the With Application block or how it's contributing to the detection of a fulfilled conditional formatting rule, so I don't know what the problem is or how to fix it without breaking the code.

Here is the test macro I'm using to check the function:

```
Sub Test():

Dim Tester As Range

Set Tester = ActiveCell

    If IsCFMet2(Tester) Then MsgBox "CF is met!"

End Sub
```

However I've gotten the same error with various range inputs, so I'm pretty confident the input itself is not the problem - I'm including it just as a precaution.

Comment: Your code ran successfully for me when applied to a cell with a very simple conditional format (`Formula1="=G8>16"`). Can you add examples of the conditional format your working with?

Comment: @xidgel Oh dear. It's comparing values in the active sheet with values in another - full formula is `=C5<>INDEX(INDIRECT("Table234"),$B5,C$4)` and I had a hell of a time getting that into a form Conditional Formatting would accept... I'm going to be pretty disappointed if that's what's breaking the check.